# Why can these variables only be null?

Tags: null, priority-queue, comparator

I have a class that implements Comparator but n1 and n2 "can only be null". Here is the class:

```
   public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Node>{

        public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {

            int n1Links = 0;
            int n2Links = 0;

            while(n1 != null){
                n1Links++;
                n1 = n1.previous;
            }
            while(n2 != null){
                n2Links++;
                n2 = n2.previous;
            }

            int n1count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n1.word.length(); i++){
                if (n1.word.charAt(i) != target.charAt(i)){
                    n1count++;
                }
            }

            int n2count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n2.word.length(); i++){
              if (n2.word.charAt(i) != target.charAt(i)){
                n2count++;
              }
            }

            int n1Total = n1Links + n1count;
            int n2Total = n2Links + n2count;

            if(n1Total > n2Total){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(n1Total < n2Total){
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }       
    }
```

Later I have this:

```
Queue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(1000, new MyComparator());
```

which uses the comparator, and then I start offering nodes to the queue right after.

The program is a words game solver, which is meant to find a way to get from word X to word Y by only changing 1 letter at a time. The point of the comparator is to help with some of the sorting.

Any idea why n1 and n2 can only be null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was missing something conceptual but it was a simple mistake:

as I increment n1Links and n2Links, I eventually set n1 and n2 to be null.

Therefore, when I try to take the size of n1 or n2, of course, they will be null.